# Sum of command line arguments?

Tags: shell, scripting, arithmetic, numeric-data

How would I create a bash script that the user can use to sum any amount of command line arguments, but it will also ignore incompatible arguments? For example, say my script is called sum:

```
sum 10 -argument1 -argument2 -argument3 20
```

30

```
sum 7 -argument1 2 -argument2 1 -argument3
```

10

Comment: What qualifies as an incompatible argument? What about -12, 1.2, 1,200,000, 1e2, 0x2, 0x4p5, nan, infinity, 2#1100, 0b1001, VII? Which of those qualify? Is 010 to be treated as octal or decimal? Should the locale be honoured when parsing radix and thousand separators?

Comment: (010), or binary @StéphaneChazelas :)

Comment: integers should qualify as compatible arguments

Comment: Very similar to [bash script for work](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/482822)

Comment: 0xff, 010, 0b101, 1,200,000, -12, +12, 1.1e2, 0x4p5, 2#1100, VII are all some representation of some integer, should they be considered?

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, assuming the sum and each individual number argument can fit in your system's `long` type, and only considering sequences of decimal digits with an optional leading `-` sign:

```
#! /bin/sh -
awk 'BEGIN{
  sum = 0
  for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
    if (ARGV[i] ~ /^-?[0123456789]+$/)
      sum += ARGV[i]
  print sum}' "$@"
```

For arbitrary precision, you can use `bc`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
awk 'BEGIN{
  for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
    if (ARGV[i] ~ /^-?[0123456789]+$/)
      print "s+="ARGV[i]
  print "s"}' "$@" | bc
```

Example:

```
$ ./sum1 999999999999999999999999 1
999999999999999983222784
$ ./sum2 999999999999999999999999 1
1000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

One (nonoptimal) example to do the sum:

```
echo "$@" |awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) j+=$i} END {print j}'
```

(assuming number is everything `awk` accept as such)

Example:

```
./ff 1 2 3.1   0x10 0100
86.1
```

And warning: any word which start with number will be interpreted as number

Comment: For `awk`, in that context, `1WHATEVER2` would be understood as `1`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelasm true, but this accept integer, float, with exponent, hex, octal.....

Comment: Unquoted `$@` might as well be `$*`

Comment: ... and so you should use `"$@"` so the parameter `"*"` does not expand to a list of files.

Comment: Answer edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility

```
printf "%s\n" "$@" | awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

It takes each argument from the command line and prints it, one per line. The `awk` script accepts this data and adds up non-zero positive values, printing the result when it's received all the data

Example

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%s\n" "$@" | awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {s+=$1} END {print s}'

./sum 1 -argument2 2 -argument4 3
6
```

If you could guarantee that your numeric arguments contained only digits you could simplify the check expression from `$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/` to `$1+0 > 0`.

Comment: That fails to exclude arguments like `$'foo\n1234'`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas indeed. Let's get a handle on what constitutes a number, first?